# Create 24bit Bitmap with Imagemagick with special background color used for transparency

Tags: command-line, bitmap, imagemagick, batch-processing

I am creating oldskool sprite images for an older gamedev software that loads 24-bit BMP only. The software detects the top left pixel color and makes it transparent on runtime.

I am trying to generate such BMP images with Imagemagick from transparent PNGs that I have, but I need the background to be lime #32cd32.

The following command in a batch file just makes a 24bit BMP file but the transparent areas appear black no matter what.

```
convert %1 -format bmp -type truecolor -background lime BMP3:"out.bmp"
```

Comment: So what do you want to do? Make the top-left pixel of each image lime? Or replace all transparent pixels with lime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "-flatten" option:

```
convert $1 -background "#32cd32" -flatten BMP3:out.bmp
```

This composites the transparent image against the specified background color.

In ImageMagick, "lime" is saturated green (#00ff00). If you want #32cd32 use ' -background "#32cd32" '

Answer (score 0):

Hard to estimate the issue without seeing the image, bit I would expect the alpha needs to be removed & replaced by the background color.

```
convert %1 -format bmp \
           -type truecolor \
           -alpha Remove \
           -background lime \
           BMP3:"out.bmp"
```

See "[Alpha Remove](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#alpha_remove)" section.

> The "`-alpha Remove`" method (added to IMv6.7.5) is designed to remove the transparency from an image, using the current "`-background`".

Comment: That didn't work, I also tried -alpha off, but nothing.